# Triggering http request in Cloud Functions for Firebase to pull data from Firebase DB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So I have this simple data in my Firebase DB

[Snapshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF5Ea.png)

How should I write the function in Cloud Functions so if I open a link like `https://example.com/292322` it will return just text "7777777777"

I have something like that so far, but I'm sure it's off, cause I'm a noob. Thx!

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.urlPubkey = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  database.ref('pubkeys').orderByChild('url').equalTo(req).once('value', snapshot => {
    const match = snapshot.val();
    if (match) {
      res.status(200).send("PUBKEY GOES HERE:)");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase cloud functions you can access your data using `snapshot.val().variableName` so in this case `const key = snapshot.val().pubkey`

I would change your code so it looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.urlPubkey = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  database.ref('pubkeys').orderByChild('url').equalTo(req).once('value', snapshot => {
    const match = snapshot.val();
    if (match) {
      res.status(200).send(match.pubkey)");
    }
  });
}
```

Or this:

```
exports.urlPubkey = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  database.ref('pubkeys').orderByChild('url').equalTo(req).once('value', snapshot => 
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      res.status(200).send(snapshot.val().pubkey)");
    }
  });
```

Or even this:

```
 exports.urlPubkey = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  database.ref('pubkeys').orderByChild('url').equalTo(req).once('value', snapshot => 
    if (snapshot..hasChild(pubkey)) {
      res.status(200).send(snapshot.val().pubkey)");
    }
  });
```